# Python long time script running huge RAM and swap memory consumption

Tags: python, csv, serial-port, export-to-csv

I am trying to write python script that will periodically (each 20ms) read the data from USB port and write obtained data to .csv file. Program need to run on RaspberryPi 3B for at least 1 week. But now I am facing the problem with RAM and swap memory consumption. After 9 hours of running Linux killing my process with just one word 'Killed' in terminal. I have checked the RAM usage using psutil module and it seems like the problem is the RAM and swap usage (1 min before crash it was 100% of swap is used overall processes and 57% of RAM is in use by this process). I was trying to find out where is this memory leakage happening by using memory profiler, so it seems like the problem is in `csv_append` function (after 10 minutes of running it increments 7Mb of data), but when I have a closer look on this function with @profiler decorator it seems like there is no leakage.

Here is an example of this function:

```
def _csv_append(self,data):
        """
        Appends to .csv file
        """
        with open(self.last_file_name, 'a') as csvfile:
            csv_writter = csv.writer(csvfile)
            csv_writter.writerow(data)
```

Is there anything that I can improve in my program so it will stop memory leaking and work for a long time without get killed by Linux OOM? In main loop function there is nothing more then reading bytes, interpreting them as `int` using `int.from_bytes()`, calling `csv_append()` and wait if some time left to ensure 0.02s period

Thank you for your help :)

Analyze memory consumption using memory profiler, no info that can help. Seems like the problem in `csv_append()` but there is no leakage
Delete all variables each cycle and use garbage collector `gc.collect()`

Comment: Just to confirm: the `data` is not accumulated in the main loop, right? so every time it's only one row

Comment: @westandskif  Yes, there is data=[] statement at the beginning of each iteration. Also i have tried to add del data  and other variables, but it does not help

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ZachYoung nope

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following little script:

```py
import csv

Iterations = 1_000

def csv_append(data):
    with open("log.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(data)

for i in range(Iterations):
    data = [i, "foo", "bar"]
    csv_append(data)
```

and got some basic stats with `/usr/bin/time -l ./main.py`:

| Iterations | Real_time | Peak_mem_footprint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_000 | 0.06 | 5_718_848 |
| 1_000_000 | 22.08 | 5_833_664 |

I'm not even clearing `data` and memory is virtualy unchanged with 1000 times more iterations.  I don't think it's the CSV file opening/writing.

I think there's something else in your program/setup you need to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I dont know what else it can be. Is it possible that data after being sended to cav_append somehow get lost after being written?